# ORA-12514 :TNS listner does not currently know the services requested in connection description .i am able to connect to the sqlplus and SQL Developer

Tags: asp.net, oracle

i am able to connect to orcale 12c using the sqlDeveloper and SQL Plus
username:SYSTEM
password:password

but when i am writing API using the ASP.Net and Try to connect to Oracle i am getting the

> ORA-12514 :TNS :listner does not currently know the services requested in connection description .

```
# TNSNames.ora sample entry
#
# alias =
#  (DESCRIPTION =
#    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myserver.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1521))
#    (CONNECT_DATA =
#      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
#      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
#    )
#  )


#
# You can modify the entry below for your own database.
# <data source alias> = Name to use in the connection string Data Source
# <hostname or IP> = name or IP of the database server machine
# <port> = database server machine port to use
# <database service name> = name of the database service on the server

<data source alias> =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =myserver.mycompany.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )
```